# MYSQL top 2 salaried employees in each department and average department salary

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, average, distinct, record

MySQL, top 2 salaried employees in each department and average department salary.
I was able to retrive the top two salaried employees in each department with, but i dont know how to inlude average department salary

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee e1
WHERE 2 > (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Salary)
           FROM Employee e2
           WHERE e2.Salary > e1.Salary
           AND e1.Dept = e2.Dept
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new at sql myself but I don't think you would be able to include the average by department in the same query. Your where statement will have an effect on your selection therefore any average you queried would only be the average of the rows returned by the where statement. It would seem to me (again in my limited experience) that a second query would have to be made to render the average salaries using something like

```
SELECT AVG(e1.salary),  AVG(e2.salary), DISTINCT e1.dept, DISTINCT e2.dept
```

FROM Employee e1
GROUP BY e1.dept, e2.dept